# Oracle - How to sum related items?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a set of data I am wanting to report on (in Oracle 12c).  I am wanting to show the sum of certain groupings, based on the value of the 'ITEM' column.  If ITEM = ('A', 'B' or 'C'), then they get "grouped" together and the values for columns Cost1 and Cost2 are summed up. This is called "Group1".  Group2 contains ITEMSs ('D, E, F').  There are only 6 groupings, made up of around 13 static/fixed items. I know exactly what the items are in each grouping.

Here is a set of sample data, with borders showing what should be grouped together.  The 2nd listing shows what the output should look like.  I think i am wanting to sum within a case statement, but I just can't seem to wrap my head around it...

[image: Grouping output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `CASE` statement is good for this type of one-off value transformation:

```
SELECT
  Year,
  CASE
    WHEN Item IN ('A', 'B', 'C') THEN 'Group1'
    WHEN Item IN ('D', 'E', 'F') THEN 'Group2'
    ELSE 'Others' END AS Item,
  SUM(Cost1),
  SUM(Cost2)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY
  Year,
  CASE
    WHEN Item IN ('A', 'B', 'C') THEN 'Group1'
    WHEN Item IN ('D', 'E', 'F') THEN 'Group2'
    ELSE 'Others' END;
```

Note that the `GROUP BY` expressions must be stated *exactly* as they are in the column selection list, except you have to drop the alias (`AS Item`).

Comment: To prevent `null` from summing up (and getting `null`) you probably want `SUM(NVL(Cost1, 0))` or similar construction

Comment: Normally I'd do something like that, but the sample output has a null result where the input is null (Year 15/Group 1/Cost 1). Year 15/Group 2/Cost 1 will be fine: Oracle will sum the 3 and ignore the null, so the result will be 3.

Answer (score 3):

Look like you want `Group By` query:

```
  select Year,
         case
           when item = 'A' or item = 'B' or item = 'C' then
             'Group1' 
           else 
             'Group2' 
         end as Item 
         Sum(nvl(Cost1, 0)) as Cost1, -- note NVL to prevent nulls from summing
         Sum(nvl(Cost2, 0) as Cost2
    from MyTable
group by Year,
         Item
```

Answer (score 2):

If the values for groups are not stored then the simplest apporach is to use a case statement and an aggregate function.  You could create a cte with the values for easier maintenance; or possibly a [pipelined tablefunction](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14289/dcitblfns.htm)

```
Select year, case when item in ('A','B','C') then 'Group1'
            when item in ('D','E','F' then 'GROUP2' else
            'Unhandled' end as Item, Sum(Cost1) as cost1, Sum(Cost2) as cost2
From TableName
Group by year, case when item in ('A','B','C') then 'Group1'
            when item in ('D','E','F' then 'GROUP2' else
            'Unhandled' end
```

Answer (score 1):

Additional to the mapping with CASE you may extract the mapping logic in the dedicated table `myItem`

```
  CREATE TABLE  myItem 
   ("ITEM" VARCHAR2(1), 
    "GROUP_ID" VARCHAR2(6), 
     PRIMARY KEY ("ITEM")
   );
```

and join to this table to get the group before GROUPing

```
with add_group as (
select a.*, b.group_id from myTable a
left outer join myItem b
on a.item = b.item
)
select .... your GROUP BY query here
```

This will keep the query more stable even if new items or groups emerges.